# Collapse navigation tree when hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a navigation tree that nicely deploys a submenu (which contains a map) when you click in and it hides nicely when mousing out without requiring further clicking thanks to the dropdown-toggle class. I would like it to collapse, so that, when you mouse over again, it would be collapsed, as in the initial situation.

Please find the html code here:

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">           
   <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">'Buscar'</a>                          
      <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
         <li><label class="tree-toggler nav-header">'Por región'></label>
            <ul class="nav nav-list tree" style="display: none;">
                <object id="mapa" type="image/svg+xml" data="mapa.svg" width="280" height="300"></object>
            </ul>
        </li>
        ...
```

I also include the script code:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('label.tree-toggler').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(300);
        });
    });
```

Comment: please make a jsfiddle of your code at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: It's easier to take a look here: http://79.170.44.126/eee.alvaro.com/pruebas/prog_16.php, select «Buscar», and then «Por región». You'll see a map displayed. I would like it to collapse when mousing out of the menu. Thanks.

Comment: that doesn't show any code

Comment: The simplified version of the code is on stackoverflow. On the site you can see it work.

Comment: put the the tree into the inner div, bind mouse over event to expand the tree and mouse out event to collapse the tree
<ul class="nav nav-list" ><div class="tree">
                <object id="mapa" type="image/svg+xml" data="mapa.svg" width="280" height="300"></object></div>
            </ul>

Comment: How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I played around in Chrome Console on your link ([79.170.44.126/eee.alvaro.com/pruebas/prog_16.php](http://%2079.170.44.126/eee.alvaro.com/pruebas/prog_16.php)) and came up with this.

Try adding this inside your `$(document).ready`:

```
$(".dropdown").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#arbol").parent().children('ul.tree').hide(300);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a million, StoneRanger!